# Why access struct's member using pointer or struct is ok?

Tags: go

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

type Vertex struct {
    X, Y float64
}

func (v Vertex) Scale(f float64) {
    v.X = v.X * f
    v.Y = v.Y * f
}

func (v Vertex) Abs() float64 {
    return math.Sqrt(v.X*v.X + v.Y*v.Y)
}

func main() {
    v := &Vertex{3, 4}
    fmt.Println(v.X)
    fmt.Println(v.Abs())
}
```

Here is my code:
for `v := &Vertex{3, 4}`, `v` is a pointer which point to `Vertex{3, 4}`,
but i find `fmt.Println(v.X)` is ok for `v := Vertex{3, 4}` or `v := &Vertex{3, 4}`,
also for function `func (v Vertex) Abs() float64` which is used for `Vertex` type, but using `* Vertex` type to call it is also ok.

what's the reason?

Comment: Very simple: Because the language specification allows this. Accessing struct members through pointers is so common that e.g. C has -> for this, Go is even shorter.

Comment: I mean, they are equal? both right?

Comment: That would be a good time to look it up in the spec which also describes subtilities regarding embeded types: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Selectors